# Getting euclidean distance between vector A and C without anyway of retrieving them when their distances with a common vector B is known

Tags: computational-geometry, convergence, numpy, machine-learning, distance-measure

**Motivation**:

My plan is to get the overall euclidean distance matrix for all the vectors in N number of dataset. Each dataset is basically an array of n-dimensional points. For e.g: A dataset can be like [[1,2,3,...n],[1,2,3,..n],...[1,2,3,n]]. However, the datasets are not gonna be shared to a single entity for which I cannot compile them and thus will not know all the points to calculate pairwise euclidean distance for some similarity calculation and clustering analysis and modeling. However, I will be only notified what are the common vectors in the datasets and distance of the vectors in any dataset with respect to those common vectors without knowing or passing the point's coordinates. If the dataset could be shared in the same model, I wouldn't have to face this distributed calculation problem.

**Details**:

A and C are two n-dimensional vectors from two different dataset. They have a common vector B. I want to calculate euclidean distance between A and C without exposing A and C, rather using B. Lets say ED(A,B) is calculated in model_1 and ED(B,C) is calculated in model_2, I can easily use ED(A,B) i.e AB and ED(B,C) i.e BC to compute ED(A,C). However, if someone know B they can easily find out A and C. Even if B is a randomly created common point, if it available, A and C can also be found. Is it possible to use B such that A and C cannot be retrieve in anyway. I have looked into differential privacy, PATE, SMPC techniques but they have their limitations in preserving privacy.

**Work done so far** :

https://www.online-python.com/Pq7OhM8FJe

**Question**

Given the euclidean distance between vector A and vector B, and that between vector B and vector C, how to calculate the euclidean-distance between point A and C such that there is no way to retrieve A and C even if B is known?

Any computation technique I can follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure that there are people who can answer this question in scicomp.SE, but it is more appropriate for the computer science stackexchange.

Comment: I will really appreciate if someone give me some guidance..really stucked on it and thinking about it everyday

Comment: What is the aggregation operation you are referring to?

Comment: I want to get  the 45 points distance matrix from the distance matrix of 15 points in 3 different dataset

Comment: Are you imagining that combining _A, B, C_ will somehow reduce the amount of work you need to do versus computing the combined matrix all at once? I'm not sure how knowing about distances within the small matrices helps you know distances in the big matrix, eg, the distance between point 1 and point n.

Comment: @Richard, thank you for your comment. I have explained my question in different way to the following stackexchange link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217205/get-distance-between-point-a-and-c-when-their-distances-with-a-common-point-b-is/4217514 please let me know if you can enlighten me towards solution 

Comment: @ShihabUllah: If you're moving your question to math.SE, you might delete/close your question here.

Comment: @Richard, I didn't move the question, it is just portraited differently in math.se and I am sure there are some one knowledgeable here who can give me some answer.

Comment: Based on your question on Math.SE you can't get any information beyond the triangle inequality. The trivial case is when $A$ and $C$ are the same and then distance is 0. The other extreme case is when the three points are collinear and the distance is the sum of the distances. So, I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @nicoguaro, A and C are two n-dimensional vectors from two different dataset. They have a common vector B. I want to calculate euclidean distance between A and C without exposing A and C, rather using B. Lets say ED(A,B) is calculated in model_1 and ED(B,C) is calculated in model_2, I can easily use ED(A,B) i.e AB and ED(B,C) i.e BC to compute ED(A,C). However, if someone know B they can easily find out A and C. So how can I use B such that  A and C cannot be retrieve in anyway. I have looked into differential privacy, PATE, SMPC techniques but they have their limitations in preserving privacy

Comment: @nicoguaro, I have updated the question with more context and work done so far. Nevertheless, I will really appreciate if anyone can help regarding it

Comment: I think I have a way to obfuscate it, but I don't think complete privacy is possible without sacrificing accurate computation of the distance from A to C. Complete privacy is obtained by sending the distances |AB| and |BC| rather than the difference vectors, then 0<= |AC| <= |AB|+|BC|. I can work on it a little bit more if obfuscation is enough.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, thanks for the reply. Yes, you are right that in order to ensure complete privacy, I can only send the distance |AB| and |AC| rather than the difference of the two vectors (as anyone can get A or C if they know B). I am open to your approach and its totally fine if accurate computation of the euclidean distance needs to be sacrificed unless its a huge margin of error. Please let know me if there is any possible work-around or technique. Thanking you in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, did you manage to have any thoughts related to it?

Comment: I am imagining something similar to how GPS works, I tell you how far I am to a set of points but not accurately; but that becomes equivalent to giving the location but adding some perturbation. I don't know if that is good enough for your application.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, on what basis you are thinking to calculate how far you are from point for e.g. B? Sounds interesting. Please elaborate in details so that I can understand whether it will serve my purpose or not.